# How to cancel the task?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I override BackButton in my app and show MessageDialog.

```
 public Scenario_3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }


private async void HardwareButtons_BackPresseed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want exit?");

        dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("yes") { Id = 0 });
        dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("no") { Id = 1 });

        dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
        dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

        if (result.Label == "yes")
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));

            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Clear();
        }
```

[image]

After navigating to BlankPage1 I again see MessageDialog if press on BackButton.
How can I cancel this override after navigating?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without a good [mcve] and a more clear problem statement. But it looks like you've just forgotten to unsubscribe from the `BackPressed` event when navigating away from the current page.

Comment: Have you tried for example to use a *flag*, to check if your button/method has been previously invoked?

Comment: Peter Duniho, thank you! Your avice solved this problem.

Comment: It would be nice if @Romasz could post his comment as an answer and you could mark it as an answer so more people looking for the solution to this can quickly find a good answer.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer It's hard to write a good answer here without getting some more information from OP - if he uses wide-app back event or only for page specific + some more details. It also seems that Peter's advice has solved OP's problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I've overlooked @PeterDuniho's comment actually.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to my comment, it appears that you've simply forgotten to unsubscribe from the `BackPressed` event when you navigate away from the page. Doing so will ensure that the event handler is called only when you want.

For example:

```
private async void HardwareButtons_BackPresseed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want exit?");

    dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("yes") { Id = 0 });
    dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("no") { Id = 1 });

    dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
    dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

    if (result.Label == "yes")
    {
        // Leaving this page. Stop listening for Back button presses.
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));

        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Correct. Even if you navigate away from the page, it will continue to receive events until it is GCed. Unsubscribing in the `NavigatedFrom` override would be even better, in case you later add code to programmatically go back.